# Vegetarian yatai food options in Fukuoka?

Tags: japan, restaurants, dietary-restrictions, fukuoka

A friend of mine is soon visiting Fukuoka and would like to sample the famous local *yatai* food stalls:

[image]

([courtesy Jacklee on Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Yatai_in_Fukuoka,_Fukuoka#/media/File:Yatai_beside_Naka-gawa,_Fukuoka,_Japan_-_20110525-02.jpg))

However, she's vegetarian, while most of Fukuoka's famous dishes (Hakata ramen pork noodles, mentaiko cod roe etc) are not.  [Browsing the menu of a random stall](http://yataimamichan.daa.jp/), they do seem to list a number of vegetarianish items (*moyashi itame* stirfried bean sprouts, *nasumiso* eggplant with miso, etc), but knowing Japan, many will actually include bacon and other surprises.  To calibrate the difficulty level, she's ok with traces of dashi/stock etc, but not actual chunks of meat or fish.

**What vegetarian dishes can you expect to find at Fukuoka's yatais**?  Recommendations for specific yatai also welcome.

Comment: Doubtful there'll be vegetarian-friendly yatai – at least knowingly. There will be a few vegetable dishes, but even stuff based on the Japanese version of kimchi, *kimuchi*, like the kimutama, might not be vegetarian (as kimchi has shrimp/oyster in it). Yatai is not an easy place for vegetarians. Good food though :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure there's going to be no such thing as vegetarian *yatai* stalls at least I've certainly never noticed any there; but I do thoroughly recommend that those of a vegetarian persuasion -- or not, for that matter -- visit the Haze Rouge macrobiotic restaurant:

- [Haze Rouge review on TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g1022364-d6052556-r284003931-La_Restaurant_du_Haze-Kurume_Fukuoka_Prefecture_Kyushu_Okinawa.html)
- [Haze Rouge review on HappyCow](https://www.happycow.net/reviews/haze-rouge-fukuoka-41875)

If there's *anywhere* that can make you authenticish vegetarian *yatai,* that's going to be the place.